# Fulltext index search on sqlserver 2008 view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view, indexing, full-text-search

While I'm trying

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[FULLTEXT_VIEW] WITH SCHEMABINDING AS

SELECT ID, NAME FROM [dbo].VIEW_TABLE

GO
```

I always get this message: Cannot schema bind view 'dbo.FULLTEXT_VIEW'. 'dbo.FULLTEXT_VIEW' is invalid for schema binding. 
What's wrong?

Comment: are you sure the owner of database in your case is dbo ???

Comment: sure mate, dbo is the owner..

Comment: try the solution provided here.. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/6f4b03bf-2df3-4f3f-91b1-66c0dcfb0236/problem-with-creating-view hope it helps